# datetimepicker not working with bootstrap 4?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-datetimepicker

```js
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#dob').datetimepicker();
    });
</script>
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" integrity="sha256-yMjaV542P+q1RnH6XByCPDfUFhmOafWbeLPmqKh11zo=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js" integrity="sha256-4iQZ6BVL4qNKlQ27TExEhBN1HFPvAvAMbFavKKosSWQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js" integrity="sha256-5YmaxAwMjIpMrVlK84Y/+NjCpKnFYa8bWWBbUHSBGfU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/js/all.js" integrity="sha256-2JRzNxMJiS0aHOJjG+liqsEOuBb6++9cY4dSOyiijX4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group" id="dob">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Date Of Birth">
            <div class="input-group-append">
            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain `Not working` part?

Comment: i have done everything from my side but its not working even not giving any error in console.

Comment: give `id` to `input` tag instead of `div`. `<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Date Of Birth" id="dob">`

Comment: not working with input

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After change datetimepicker CDN it is working as expected.

Hope this will help you.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.0.1/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.0.1/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/js/all.js" integrity="sha256-2JRzNxMJiS0aHOJjG+liqsEOuBb6++9cY4dSOyiijX4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1" data-target-input="nearest">
          <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#datetimepicker1" />
          <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetimepicker1" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
            <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

To localize the datetimepicker Need to add locale CDN after moment.min.js Like the below example.

You can find locale CDN URLs from Here -> https://cdnjs.com/libraries/moment.js

```js
$(function() {
  $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/locale/fa.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.0.1/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.0.1/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/js/all.js" integrity="sha256-2JRzNxMJiS0aHOJjG+liqsEOuBb6++9cY4dSOyiijX4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1" data-target-input="nearest">
          <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#datetimepicker1" />
          <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetimepicker1" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
            <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please tell me how can I localize this datetimepicker?

Comment: @Rey I edited the answer. please check, It may help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" integrity="sha256-yMjaV542P+q1RnH6XByCPDfUFhmOafWbeLPmqKh11zo=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js" integrity="sha256-4iQZ6BVL4qNKlQ27TExEhBN1HFPvAvAMbFavKKosSWQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js" integrity="sha256-5YmaxAwMjIpMrVlK84Y/+NjCpKnFYa8bWWBbUHSBGfU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/js/all.js" integrity="sha256-2JRzNxMJiS0aHOJjG+liqsEOuBb6++9cY4dSOyiijX4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group" >
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Date Of Birth" id="dob">
            <div class="input-group-append">
            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#dob').datetimepicker();
    });

 </script>
```

Comment: just display blank box

Comment: click on box time-picker will display.

Comment: its display :) but i want to display calendar

Comment: You have to change your cdn.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" integrity="sha256-yMjaV542P+q1RnH6XByCPDfUFhmOafWbeLPmqKh11zo=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js" integrity="sha256-4iQZ6BVL4qNKlQ27TExEhBN1HFPvAvAMbFavKKosSWQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js" integrity="sha256-5YmaxAwMjIpMrVlK84Y/+NjCpKnFYa8bWWBbUHSBGfU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/js/all.js" integrity="sha256-2JRzNxMJiS0aHOJjG+liqsEOuBb6++9cY4dSOyiijX4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group" id="dob">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Date Of Birth">
            <div class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>    
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#dob').datetimepicker(); 
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

You need to downgrade your bootstrap to version 3
and change your icon wrapper class from input-group-append to input-group-addon

Comment: i can't use lower version @Ron Michael

Comment: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css is meant for bootstrap 3 not version 4, you can check it yourself

Comment: Your answer doesn't fit to the question's scope. -1

Answer (score 1):

Check out this code. Might help you.

```js
$(function(){
  $('#dob').datetimepicker({
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
    icons: {
      previous: "fas fa-chevron-left",
      next: "fas fa-chevron-right",
    },
  });
  $('.input-group-append').click(function(){
   $('.form-control').trigger('focus');
  });
});
```

```css
.input-group-append { cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker-standalone.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Date Of Birth" id="dob">
            <div class="input-group-append">
            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
  </div>  
</div>
```